# ajax request not going through javascript

Tags: php, ajax

trying to send POST request to script via ajax, not calling the script

```
<script>

 function claimitem() {

     var val=document.getElementById('itemid').value;
        alert(val); //shows as 4 correct
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "scripts/claim.php", 
    data: {id: val},
    dataType: "json",   
    success: function(data) {
        alert("success"); //does not show

    }

}); 


window.location = "profile.php";

}

</script>
```

here i am calling the javascript function

```
<input type="submit" onclick="claimitem()" class="btn" value="claim - <?php echo $ebase;?> PP">
```

my claim.php looks like this what is wrong with my ajax call???

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'  && isset($_POST['id'])) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `$.ajax`, you're *starting* an asynchronous task. This task, involving a request, doesn't stop the script so the following line is immediately executed.

As the following line replaces the page, it ends the script, including the ajax request. You must call this line in the callback to let the time for the ajax request :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  "scripts/claim.php", 
    data: {id: val},
    dataType: "json",   
    success: function(data) {
        alert("success"); //does not show
        window.location = "profile.php";
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried removing window.location entirely and nothing is happening it isn't calling anything its like the button is disabled

Comment: @user2127136 Then your problem is something in the script. Try viewing the server response from a js debugging tool like Firebug's - By the way, are you returning data? Otherwise simply remove the "function(data)"'s "data".

Answer (score 0):

code looks ok better add some alert to error as if some problem with your ajax helper.
something like.

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have added this to your head tag

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

then try to change input `type="button"`

```
<input type="button" onclick="claimitem()" class="btn" value="claim - <?php echo $ebase;?> PP">
```